# How to modify a DataFrame's List to get Mean, Length and number of NaN's, while deleting the List?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert a Dataframe's information in a certain way.
Here is an example I made up to illustrate my problem. The original DataFrame looked like this:

```
Ethnicity         Employed          Weight          Gender
1                 1                 NaN             1
3                 0                 50              0
1                 1                 65              0
2                 1                 60              1
2                 0                                 0
3                 1                 NaN             NaN
1                 NaN               75              1
2                 0                 50              0
3                 NaN               NaN             1
1                 0                 87              1
```

Using groupby Ethnicity, I got lists in the columns:

```
Ethnicity        Employed           Weight          Gender
1                [1,1,NaN,0]        [NaN,65,75,87]  [1,0,1,1]
2                [1,0,0]            [60,50]         [1,0,0]
3                [0,1,NaN]          [50,NaN,NaN]    [0,NaN,1]
```

Until here I succeeded. Now I need the mean, the length and the number of NaN's of each list in the columns Employed, Weight and Gender, while deleting the original ones. In the end it has to look like this:

```
Ethnicity   Employed_mean   Employed_length   Employed_no_NaN   Weight_mean   Weight_length   Weight_no_NaN   Gender_mean   Gender_length   Gender_no_NaN
1            0,66            4                  1               75,66         4                  1               0,75            4              0
2            0,33            3                  0               55            2                  0               0,33            3              0
3            0,5             3                  1               50            3                  2               0,5             3              1
```

How should I go about the last step of converting the DataFrame in a pythonesque way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.apply`:

```
In [3103]: res = df.groupby('Ethnicity').agg(list)                                                                                                                                                          

In [3104]: res                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[3104]: 
                       Employed                   Weight                Gender
Ethnicity                                                                     
1          [1.0, 1.0, nan, 0.0]  [nan, 65.0, 75.0, 87.0]  [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
2               [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]        [60.0, 0.0, 50.0]       [1.0, nan, 0.0]
3               [0.0, 1.0, nan]         [50.0, nan, nan]       [0.0, nan, 1.0]

In [3102]: import numpy as np

In [3107]: res['Employed_mean'] = res.Employed.apply(lambda x: np.nanmean(x))
In [3109]: res['Employed_length'] = res.Employed.apply(lambda x: len(x))
In [3117]: res['Employed_Nan'] = res.Employed.apply(lambda x: np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(x))) 

In [3119]: res.pop('Employed')

In [3120]: res                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[3120]: 
                            Weight                Gender  Employed_mean  Employed_length  Employed_Nan
Ethnicity                                                                                             
1          [nan, 65.0, 75.0, 87.0]  [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]           0.67                4             1
2                [60.0, 0.0, 50.0]       [1.0, nan, 0.0]           0.33                3             0
3                 [50.0, nan, nan]       [0.0, nan, 1.0]           0.50                3             1
```

Similarly you can do it for remaining columns also.

**OR, in one-line:**

```
In [3137]: res.agg({"Employed":[lambda x: np.nanmean(x), len, lambda x: np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(x))], "Weight":[lambda x: np.nanmean(x), len, lambda x: np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(x))], "Gender":[lambda x
      ...: : np.nanmean(x), len, lambda x: np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(x))]})                                                                                                                                 
Out[3137]: 
          Employed                Weight                Gender             
          <lambda> len <lambda> <lambda> len <lambda> <lambda> len <lambda>
Ethnicity                                                                  
1             0.67   4        1    75.67   4        1     0.75   4        0
2             0.33   3        0    36.67   3        0     0.50   3        1
3             0.50   3        1    50.00   3        2     0.50   3        1
```